# Optimization problem "change of variables" injectivity requirement

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, change-of-variable

Consider a standard form optimization problem (4.1)

$$
\begin{alignat}{4}
&\text{minimize}\quad &&f_0(x) \\
&\text{subject to} &&f_i(x)\le 0\quad && i=1,...,m \\
& &&h_i(x)=0 && j=1,...,p
\end{alignat}
$$

On page 130 of Boyd & Vandenberghe [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf), the authors outline an equivalent optimization problem transformation via "change of variables".

> Suppose $\phi:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ is **one-to-one**, with image covering the problem domain $\mathcal D$, i.e., $\phi(\textbf{dom }\phi)\supseteq\mathcal D$. We define the functions $\tilde f_i$ and $\tilde h_i$ as
>   $$
> \tilde f_i(z)=f_i(\phi(z)),\quad i=0,...,m,\quad \tilde h_i(z)=h_i(\phi(z)),\quad i=1,...,p.
> $$
>   Now consider the problem (4.4)
>   $$
> \begin{alignat}{4}
> &\text{minimize}\quad &&\tilde f_0(z) \\
> &\text{subject to} &&\tilde f_i(z)\le 0\quad && i=1,...,m \\
> & &&\tilde h_i(z)=0 && j=1,...,p.
> \end{alignat}
> $$
>   The two problems ((4.1) and (4.4)) are clearly equivalent: if $x$ solves (4.1), then $z=\phi^{-1}(x)$ soles (4.4); if $z$ solves (4.4), then $x=\phi(z)$ solves (4.1).

I'd like to focus on the "one-to-one" requirement. *I don't see why it's there*. On page 132, a particular change of variables is used for "eliminating equality constraints":

> Suppose the function $\phi:\mathbb R^k\to\mathbb R^n$ is such that $x$ satisfies $h_i(x)=0$ $i=1,...,p$ if and only if there is some $z\in\mathbb R^k$ such that $x=\phi(z)$. The optimization problem
>   $$
> \begin{alignat}{4}
> &\text{minimize}\quad &&\tilde f_0(z)=f_0(\phi(z)) \\
> &\text{subject to} &&\tilde f_i(z)=f_i(\phi(z))\le 0\quad && i=1,...,m
> \end{alignat}
> $$
>   is then equivalent to the original problem (4.1) [...] If $z$ is optimal for the transformed, then $x=\phi(z)$ is optimal for the original problem. Conversely, if $x$ is optimal for the original problem, then (since $x$ is feasible) there is at least one $z$ such that $x=\phi(z)$. Any such $z$ is optimal for the transformed problem.

The case of "change of variables" requires $\phi$ to be one-to-one yet "eliminating equality constraints" makes no such requirement. **Why**?

Note: if you are going to answer "because otherwise $\phi^{-1}$ does not exist, so we cannot do $x=\phi^{-1}(z)$ in the change of variables case", my counter-argument would be that this does not stop the authors for the eliminating equality constraints case. They say simply pick one $z$ such that $x=\phi(z)$ and we can do the same in the change of variables case.